# I want to print data from a div with a class value but my code keeps returning additional data from another similar div

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

Here's the HTML code:

```
<div class="sizeBlock">
 <div class="size"> 
    <a class="selectSize" id="44526" data-size-original="36.5">36.5</a> 
 </div> 
 <div class="size inactive active"> 
    <a class="selectSize" id="44524" data-size-original="40">40</a> 
 </div> 
 <div class="size"> 
    <a class="selectSize" id="44525" data-size-original="40.5">40.5</a> 
 </div> 
</div>
```

I want to get the values of the id tag and the data-size-original inside `<div class="size">` only.

Here's my code:

```
for sizeBlock in soup.select('div.size a.selectSize'):
aid = sizeBlock.get('id')
size = sizeBlock.get('data-size-original')
print(aid, size)
```

The problem is that it also returns the data from `<div class="size inactive active">`

[Here's a picture of the execution of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4U4W.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could go with a more succinct method using a class attribute selector (by using as attribute selector you can limit to parent div with single appropriate class) and generate a dictionary:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

html = '''<div class="sizeBlock">
 <div class="size"> 
    <a class="selectSize" id="44526" data-size-original="36.5">36.5</a> 
 </div> 
 <div class="size inactive active"> 
    <a class="selectSize" id="44524" data-size-original="40">40</a> 
 </div> 
 <div class="size"> 
    <a class="selectSize" id="44525" data-size-original="40.5">40.5</a> 
 </div> 
</div>'''

soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
d = {i['id']:i['data-size-original'] for i in soup.select('[class=size] a')}
print(d)
```

---

Adjust dict comprehension to loop if you want to store in variables

```
for i in soup.select('[class=size] a'):
    aid = i['id'];size = i['data-size-original'] 
    print(aid, size)
```

Comment: That's useful but what I want to store them in variables.
`aid = ['id']` and `size = ['data-size-original']`

Comment: See the edit at bottom if you wish to place in variables you overwrite in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_doc = """<div class="sizeBlock">
 <div class="size"> 
    <a class="selectSize" id="44526" data-size-original="36.5">36.5</a> 
 </div> 
 <div class="size inactive active"> 
    <a class="selectSize" id="44524" data-size-original="40">40</a> 
 </div> 
 <div class="size"> 
    <a class="selectSize" id="44525" data-size-original="40.5">40.5</a> 
 </div> 
</div>"""  


soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
for sizeBlock in soup.select('div.size'):
    if sizeBlock.get('class') != ['size']:
        continue
    soup2 = sizeBlock.select('a.selectSize')[0]
    aid = soup2.get('id')
    size = soup2.get('data-size-original')
    print(aid, size)
```

Output:

```
44526 36.5
44525 40.5
```

Explanation:

```
if sizeBlock.get('class') != ['size']:
    continue
```

Will skip over any class that is not 'size' `!=` is the not equal to operator. Since for the 'size inactive active' class `get('class')` returns `['size', 'inactive', 'active']` this block is passed over in the loop.

```
sizeBlock.select('a.selectSize')
```

returns a list

```
[<a class="selectSize" data-size-original="36.5" id="44526">36.5</a>]
```

and so writing

```
sizeBlock.select('a.selectSize')[0]
```

returns the first (and only) element of this list.

Comment: Could you explain what you've done? What do `[0]` and `!= ['size']:` mean in the code?

Answer (score -1):

You can implement the functionality as below.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
all_a = soup.find_all('a')
for a in all_a:
    aid = a.get('id')
    size = a.get('data-size-original')
    print(aid, size)
```

Comment: op wants to select only the a elements. They are the ones containing the id and data-size-original

Comment: But not the element with `size inactive active`